# Определение типа введенных данных (символ, число)

Tags: c#, типы-данных, int, main

Есть такая задача: пользователь вводит любую цифру/строку, а программа должна определить какой это тип данных (например int или double) и вывести это пользователю. Как это вывести в метод Main способом "перегрузка методов"?

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {

        public static void WriteNumer(int a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is int");
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }

        public static void WriteNumber(double b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is double");
            Console.WriteLine(b);
        }

        public static void WriteNumber(string c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is string");
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }

        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Write a number: ");
            string a = Console.ReadLine();
            if (WriteNumber == a)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `bool удалосьПреобразовать = тип.TryParse(строка, out тип сконвертированноеЗначение)`

Comment: Можно пожалуйста по подробнее? Я просто начинающая

Comment: Я вам прям максимально ведь подробно все показал, нет? Прям берите, копируйте и подставляйте свои значения. например `bool isInt = int.TryParse(a, out int val);`, а дальше уже на этой основе делайте что хотите, хоть `if (isInt) {Console.WriteLine(val);}`, хоть делайте `switch`, в котором укажете все эти `.TryParse()`, хоть что угодно еще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перегрузка методов подразумевает собой, что методы имеют разную сигнатуру, в которой совпадает только название метода. Но для вашей задачи подойдет:

Код программы:

```
Console.Write("Write a number: ");
string a = Console.ReadLine();
if (int.TryParse(a, out var number1) == true) {
   Console.WriteLine($"{number1} является числом int");
} else if (double.TryParse(a, out var number2) == true){
   Console.WriteLine($"{number2} является числом double");
}
else Console.WriteLine($"{a} является строкой");
```

Результат:

```
Write a number: 4
4 является числом int
Write a number: 4ddwa
4 является строкой
Write a number: 4,33
4 является числом double
```